# Google warning - Deceptive site ahead on OAuth2 authorization code grant flow

Tags: google-search-console

We have implemented OAuth2 and using the authorization code grant flow.
Some users get the red screen of google which says deceptive ahead.

On request number 5 sometimes users receive the deceptive site ahead warning.
In the google search console I have no information regarding it and I can just report it as false flag. Then google flags it as solved but few days later it's back.
In the google search console i have 0 information whats up

[image]
I think the issue is that google think this code parameter here is malicious code, it always happens on that particular call.

```
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
```

Does anybody have an idea how to deal with this issues?

1. 302 https://auth.myapp.com/
2. 302 https://login.myapp.com/login?identifier=demo2
3. 302  https://auth.myapp.com/consent?code_challenge_method=S256&state=a2f1dc186493cfec4c01d8956f1b851c&scope=&response_type=code&approval_prompt=auto&redirect_uri=https://login.myapp.com/connect/kauth/check?identifier%3Ddemo2&client_id=myapp
4. 302  https://auth.myapp.com/authorize?code_challenge_method=S256&state=a2f1dc1864adscfec4c01d8956f1b851c&scope=&response_type=code&approval_prompt=auto&redirect_uri=https://login.myapp.com/connect/kauth/check?identifier%3Ddemo2&client_id=myapp
5. 302  https://login.myapp.com/connect/kauth/check?identifier=demo2&code=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&state=a2f1dc186493cfec4c01d8956f1b851c